# insert date from datepicker to MySQL database in php

Tags: datepicker

I'm trying to insert date from datepicker but the sql statement is not working imo.
here is the code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
{   
    $order_finish_time = $_POST['order_finish_time'];
    $note = $_POST['note'];
    $finish_query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO orderdetails SET order_finish_time=$order_finish_time AND note=$note WHERE order_id=$order_id");
    $order_r = mysqli_fetch_array($finish_query);
    if(isset($order_r))
    {   
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE orderdetails SET order_status = 'Order_Finished' WHERE order_id=$order_id");
        ?>
        <script>alert('Order confirmed!');</script>
        <script>document.location = 'orderdetails.php';</script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('Something wrong');</script>
        <script>document.location = 'orderdetails.php';</script>
        <?php
    }           
}
```

else part of the code is working and im getting something wrong message. Plese help me out if you can spot error in my code.

The form im using is:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post"> 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    Order will be finished :
    <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="order_finish_time"  required/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="confirm" id="confirm" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
   Confirm
  </button>
 </form>

 <!-- datepicker -->
 <script>
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the picture of my tables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YsVN.png)

Comment: Please show us the form and the Datepicker Plugin you are using.

Comment: Please share your database table structure and the error you are getting. I recommend you put your strings in your query in single quotes. Please consider that MySql Date, Datetime and Timestamp types only accept a few formats.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incomplete in many ways. No jQuery and jQuery UI is defined in the head.
Your form is missing the field with the name `text`.
No database connection is made.
The variable `$order_id` is not defined in your code.

Use `var_dump(mysqli_error_list($link));` after executing statements to see possible errors in your SQL. This is procedural style.

Your query is plain wrong. You cannot insert with a where clause, it is used for select, update and delete.

The correct insert query would be

```
$finish_query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (`order_finish_time`, `note`) VALUES ('$order_finish_time', '$note')");
```

Please explain what your program is supposed to do. It does not make sense the way it is written right now. This works, but since I do not know your intentions it may be -logically- wrong.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {   
    $order_finish_time = $_POST['order_finish_time'];
    $note = $_POST['note'];
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'orderdetails');
    $finish_query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (`order_finish_time`, `note`) VALUES ('$order_finish_time', '$note')");
    $order_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    if($finish_query === true)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `orderdetails` SET `order_status` = 'Order_Finished' WHERE `id`=$order_id");
        ?>
            <script>alert('Order confirmed!');</script>
            <script>document.location = 'orderdetails.php';</script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
            <script>alert('Something wrong');</script>
            <script>document.location = 'orderdetails.php';</script>
        <?php
    }           
}

?>
```

Comment: ow thanks a lot! yes my sql statement was not correct, it is a little ordering and order accepting system, i didnt post the whole code becase tried to be more clear. I got order_id by a link when i go to this page but i didnt submit the order_id with form, so my error was more of a logical, now i fixed everything and is working just fine :) thanks again for helping

Comment: No problem, it would be nice if you accept the answer or upvote it if it was useful to you. Thanks!